# CORS CI4 /public folder (kml file) when access from frontend Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, codeigniter, nuxt.js

i want to access kml file from my backend

```
try {
          for (const city of this.cities) {
            if (!city || !city.kml) {
              continue;
            }

            const baseURL = `http://localhost:8080`;
            const kmlFilePath = baseURL + city.kml;

            Omnivore.kml(kmlFilePath).addTo(customIcons);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching or adding KMZ file:', error);
        }
```

but i get cors error :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/transmitters/kmz/Untitled.kml' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
client.js:775

GET http://localhost:8080/uploads/transmitters/kmz/Untitled.kml net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

i have my cors setting :

```
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        };

    }
```

i tried to access the file from my fe, yes it works. but when the app is build, and i want to update or add new kml, i cant?

Comment: in the browser, can you see the CORS response headers for the request?

Comment: no, but i can get the img in the same /public folder without cors issue and no cors respone headers

Comment: so, no CORS headers, yet your code suggests you add them ... perhaps your code isn't doing what you think - not sure how getting an image is at all relevant to the code you posted, are you "getting" in through an AJAX request?